# Maintaining state of fragments

Tags: android, fragment, bundle

I am using fragments and I need to maintain he state of fragments as is it is traversed again. In case I have only  2 fragments they can be easily maintained through bundles.

But if I have more than 2 fragments say `Fragment 1`,`Fragment 2`,`Fragment 3`.

When I go from

```
Fragment 1--> Fragment 2--> Fragment 3
```

I get the state of Fragment 2 Maintained but the arguments of Fragment 1 gets lost. So I am unable to maintain the state of Fragment 1.

Please help me to overcome this problem.

Comment: One way of saving data would be to use a bean class and save the data of each fragment in that bean class.

Comment: And hoow would i send one bean object to another fragment as i cant create constructors in fragments

Comment: you can pass that object through bundle after making your bean class parceable.

Comment: but when i will go to F3 from F2 , bundle of F1 will be lost and i wont get the state of F1  again.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add fragment to backstatck.

Comment: i am adding fragments to backstack

Answer (score 0):

this is because offscreen page limit by default is for one page only

so you are only be able to save a single page in background 
if you want to save more pages

do

```
viewpager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
```

if you have 3 fregments then use

```
viewpager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
```

Comment: i am not using viewpager, i am using tabhost